# Isotopy and homeomorphism

Tags: general-topology, geometry, algebraic-topology, low-dimensional-topology

Let $X$ and $Y$ be  topological spaces.
Suppose we have an isotopy between maps $f, g: X\to Y$.

The question is that is there a homeomorphism $h: Y\to Y$ such that $h\circ f =g$?

I am especially interested in the case when $Y$ is a surface and $f, g$ are embeddings.

Is this true or do we need more conditions? Is there any analogous result?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by isotopy if $f$ and $g$ aren't embeddings?

Comment: (Assume f and g are embeddings) In the smooth manifold setting, If $X$ is compact and $G$ is the isotopy youve assumed, there is an "ambient isotopy" of the identity map on Y. I.e. an isotopy $H: Y\times I \rightarrow Y$ such that $H(f,t)= G$ and $H_0 = 1$. Then $H_1$ is your homeomorphism.  See Kosinski's "Differential Manifolds" theorem 5.2 in chapter 2.  I'm not sure about the non compact case. Weirdly I was just discussing this in the "differential-topology" section.

Comment: Be aware that often when people say "isotopy" they mean "ambient isotopy," and ambient isotopy does give a homeomorphism like the one you ask for.

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/157038/question-on-up-to-isotopy-when-attaching-two-spaces/157104#157104), this is not true in general in the topological case (although it is true in the differential case, as observed by Tim above). The interesting link in that answer is [this](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Isotopy_%28in_topology%29).